# Load JPA repository queries from a property file

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to load queries in a repository from a property file. For example, here:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {

    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM student where year= :le", native=true)
    public List<Student> getStudentsByLevel(@Param("le") int level);

}
```

I need to load the `"SELECT * FROM student where year= :le"` string from a property file. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Why would you want that anyway? If you really must you can put your named queries in the `orm.xml`.

Comment: Can we use xml configuration instead of @Query annotation in spring?

Comment: Sure why wouldn't you... It is just a lay around JPA you can do whatever you want. But as requested initial, why?

Comment: As shown in the initial post I'm using JPArepositories. Now I need to make my application support both mysql and oracle, Some of the quries defined for mysql database doesn't suppot oracle database. So I'm trying to make my quries configurable. Can you provide me some example of xml configuration instead of @Query ?

Comment: You should be using HQL and not SQL that way hibernate will take care of that. IMHO the flaw is that you used SQL instead of HQL...

Comment: JPQL would be better, since he is using JPA (most probable he also uses Hibernate, but you can't be sure).

Comment: But someof Mysql quries uses functions like DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL :to SECOND)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above I have overcome this problem by using xml configured named queries. Below is the example.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="hibernatePersistenceUnit">

        <!-- <mapping-file>META-INF/jpql/oracle-quries.xml</mapping-file> -->
        <mapping-file>META-INF/jpql/mysql-quries.xml</mapping-file>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

mysql-quries.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd ">

    <named-native-query name="Nodecontrol.lockNodeController">
        <query>
            SELECT * FROM student where year= :le
        </query>
    </named-native-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

In oracle-quries.xml and mysql-quries.xml I have defined all the native queries respectively. When I need to change the query without changing the class file I just need to mention the file name i need to use in persistence.xml.